# Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 154)

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I'm using `import` to add rows to a table. I have almost 600 to add but working with just the 2 below for now. My file:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_wlm_userlevel_options` ( `userlevel_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ( '341', registration_date', '2017-11-30 16:14:43#0', 'yes' ),( '341', 'transaction_id', 'WL-6806-1506616728', 'yes' );
```

There is an auto generated value (ID) before userlevel_id. I've tried including it with same results. Also tried removing "16:14:43#0" same results.
Full response***********************
Error
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 153)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 156)
SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_wlm_userlevel_options` ( `userlevel_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ( '341', registration_date', '2017-11-30 16:14:43#0', 'yes' ), ( '341', 'transaction_id', 'WL-6806-1506616728', 'yes' )
```

MySQL said: Documentation

#

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '', '2017-11-30 16:14:43#0', 'yes' ),    ( '341',
>   'transaction_id', 'WL-6806-1506' at line 2)

---

Any help appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're missing a single quote before `registration_date'`

Comment: OMG, I've looked so closely at this and could not see that. Thanks, that did it!!!